# AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, flask, xlsxwriter

Saw several similar posts but they did not solve my issue. Really not sure why the write attribute isn't being recognized. Pip installed all appropriate components.Tried playing around with the parameters for write as well. Any help is appreciated.

```
import xlsxwriter
from xlsxwriter import Workbook

wb = Workbook('C:/Users/vlad.synnes/Desktop/workbook.xlsx')
wb.add_worksheet('Data')
wb.write('test')
wb.close()
send_file('C:/Users/vlad.synnes/Desktop/workbook.xlsx', as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: This is expected behavior: `'write' in dir(wb)` returns `False`. You cannot append to an existing xlsx file with xlsxwriter.

Comment: you can write in `worksheet`, but not in `workbook` - `ws = wb.add_worksheet('Data')` `ws.write(0, 0, 'test')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write in `worksheet`, but not in `workbook`.

```
ws = wb.add_worksheet('Data') 
ws.write(0, 0, 'test')
```

Full

```
import xlsxwriter
from xlsxwriter import Workbook

wb = Workbook('C:/Users/vlad.synnes/Desktop/workbook.xlsx')

ws = wb.add_worksheet('Data')
ws.write(0, 0, 'test')

wb.close()
```

You can see it even in documentation: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html