# Want to enumerate all columns in dataframe but i get error 'XlsxWriter' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python

Dataframe is already inserted as excel table.I want to access it and set the font style for column header.

```
import pandas as pd
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('QualityReview Supplier template.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = workbook.get_worksheet_by_name('IssueData')
header_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': True,
    'fg_color': '#0000FF',
    'font_color': 'white',
    'border': 1})
for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
    writer.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)

writer.save()
```

Error is as below

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_711330/2009989865.py in <module>
     20 
     21 for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
---> 22     writer.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)
     23 
     24 writer.save()

AttributeError: 'XlsxWriter' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Comment: The error pretty much tells you, I guess. Seems like the write method that you seek may be for worksheets as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55460069/attributeerror-workbook-object-has-no-attribute-write I am not sure since I dont typically work with excel sheets. You can see it also in the docs here:
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html the xlsxwriter is used to add a worksheet and the worksheet is what has the write method.